# DLL Mutex - an example

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, dll, mutex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DLL thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579168/dll-thread-safety)

Hi

Im writting a DLL file in MS VS C++ express, which is loaded in multiple client applications at the same time, it uses shared memory with the other instances of the loaded DLL. Let us assume the DLL looks something like this:

```
#include stdafx.h  
#pragma data_seg (".TEST")  
//Shared variables  
#pragma data_seg ()  
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.TEST,RWS")  
_DLLAPI void __stdcall doCalc()  
{  
//Do critical stuff  
}
```

If `doCalc` is called simultaneously from two or more clients the system will crash.
How would I create a Mutex that "stalls" other calls if the function has already been called?
Please give an example, as I have spent the last two hours trying to find a decent one on the internet ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code of every process:

```
// At the start of every process
HANDLE sharedMemoryMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "My shared memory mutex");

// When you want to access shared memory:
DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(sharedMemoryMutex, INFINITE);

if (dwWaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 || dwWaitResult == WAIT_ABANDONED)
{
   if (dwWaitResult == WAIT_ABANDONED)
   {
      // Shared memory is maybe in inconsistent state because other program
      // crashed while holding the mutex. Check the memory for consistency
      ...
   }

   // Access your shared memory
   ...

   // After this line other processes can access shared memory
   ReleaseMutex(sharedMemoryMutex);
}
```

Comment: You too need to make sure that 1) other processes (running in the context of other users) get the same mutex and 2) that other processes have access to the mutex as well. Do this by 1) using the "Global\" prefix on the mutex name and 2) by specifying an appropriate security descriptor when creating the mutex.

Comment: @villintehaspam, your assertions are valid, but I doubt they apply in OP's case

Comment: you are probably right - I just think that this information should be present so that the OP can make an informed decision whether to care about this or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changed the code so that it reflects your answer, could you take a look at it and tell if it is valid?

Comment: @sigvardsen, well, ignoring the fact that you have some strange ... dots in your code, it looks valid to me :-). Only you know if it is actually valid. Run and test it. If something goes wrong ask another question, saying what exactly went wrong, and don't edit this question so that it becomes another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the "Using Mutex Objects" sample, located at MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686927%28VS.85%29.aspx).  In order to have a mutex shared between processes, you'll need to change the [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) call to take a name.

Comment: You need to make sure that 1) other processes (running in the context of other users) get the same mutex and 2) that other processes have access to the mutex as well. Do this by 1) using the "Global\" prefix on the mutex name and 2) by specifying an appropriate security descriptor when creating the mutex.

Comment: If he has shared writeable memory mapped between processes running as different users, he has a huge security hole.  Relying on a mutex in the global namespace is another huge security hole since it can be trivially squattable.

Comment: Right: the same name scope should be used for both the mutex and the file mapping, and probably both should be session-local.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a shared file mapping object to create shared memory, not using the linker to mark a section as shared.  A relatively easy way to manage this is to put all shared variables into a single `struct` and then cast the return value from `MapViewOfFile` to be a pointer to this struct.

Of course, you can't have pointers in this shared area, but you can exchange index information (referring to an array in the shared area of course) between processes.

Even a linker shared section is not guaranteed to load at the same address in all processes.